# SQL Server Job history 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have many jobs scheduled in SQL Server R2.
And each job may contain several Steps under it.

I want the lastrundate, lastrunstatus, lastrunduration, lastrunmessage, nextrundate FOR EACH AND EVERY STEP under EACH JOB.

I have this query with me which works fine.

The only issue is, it is not allowing me to convert the **LastRunDateTime** String to **DateTime**

```
SELECT 
[sJOB].[job_id] AS [JobID],
[sJOB].[name] AS [JobName],
[sJOBS].step_name AS [StepName],
CASE 
    WHEN [sJOBS].[last_run_date] IS NULL OR [sJOBS].[last_run_time] IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE 
            CAST(CAST([sJOBS].[last_run_date] AS VARCHAR(8))
            + ' ' 
            + STUFF(
                STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJOBS].[last_run_time] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                    , 3, 0, ':')
                , 6, 0, ':') AS DATETIME)
  END AS [LastRunDateTime],
 CASE [sJOBH].[run_status]
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Running' -- In Progress
  END AS [LastRunStatus],
  STUFF(
        STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJOBS].[last_run_duration] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
            , 3, 0, ':')
        , 6, 0, ':') 
    AS [LastRunDuration (HH:MM:SS)],
  [sJOBH].[message] AS [LastRunStatusMessage],
  CASE [sJOBSCH].[NextRunDate]
    WHEN 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST(
            CAST([sJOBSCH].[NextRunDate] AS CHAR(8))
            + ' ' 
            + STUFF(
                STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJOBSCH].[NextRunTime] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                    , 3, 0, ':')
                , 6, 0, ':')
            AS DATETIME)
  END AS [NextRunDateTime]
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] WHERE enabled = 1) AS [sJOB]
LEFT JOIN sysjobsteps [sJOBS]
        ON([sJOB].[job_id] = [sJOBS].[job_id])
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                [job_id],
                MIN([next_run_date]) AS [NextRunDate],
                MIN([next_run_time]) AS [NextRunTime]
            FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules]
            GROUP BY [job_id]
        ) AS [sJOBSCH]
    ON [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJOBSCH].[job_id]
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                [job_id],
                [run_date],
                [run_time],
                [run_status],
                [run_duration],
                [message],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                                        PARTITION BY [job_id] 
                                        ORDER BY [run_date] DESC, [run_time] DESC
                  ) AS RowNumber
            FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory]
            WHERE [step_id] = 0
        ) AS [sJOBH]
    ON [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJOBH].[job_id]
    AND [sJOBH].[RowNumber] = 1
ORDER BY [JobName]
```

**The CAST() function on LastRunDateTime gives me following error**

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Could you try narrowing it down, and providing a smaller repro?  I don't think you need all of that huge query, you already know which columns are causing the issue.  Then, show us the query, and the string results of the query WITHOUT the CAST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee that you're having exactly the same issue, but on a system I tested this on, I got the same error because some of the job steps had `0` as a value for `last_run_date`.

I fixed this with the following amendment to your query. Perhaps this will work for you too.

```
...
CASE 
    WHEN [sJOBS].[last_run_date] IS NULL OR [sJOBS].[last_run_time] IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN [sJOBS].[last_run_date] = 0 THEN NULL --<< line added here <<
    ELSE 
            CAST(CAST([sJOBS].[last_run_date] AS VARCHAR(8))
            + ' ' 
            + STUFF(
                STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJOBS].[last_run_time] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                    , 3, 0, ':')
                , 6, 0, ':') AS DATETIME)
  END AS [LastRunDateTime],
...
```

Comment: Excellent! I didnt see that coming! :)
I added your line to my OR conditions list
    WHEN [sJOBS].[last_run_date] IS NULL OR [sJOBS].[last_run_time] IS NULL OR [sJOBS].[last_run_date] = 0 THEN NULL